# how to pass job name in plugin "trigger parameterized build on other projects" in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

in this plugin , it require "Projects to build",  it says
"A comma separated list of projects to build"

I set a parameter in my job configuration , let's say it's named A

A="job1,job2,job3"

in "Projects to build", I pass A
Projects to build : ${A}

but it not work, so how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution using a build step (and not a post-build step) with the trigger parameterized plugin.

Add a parameter to define the child job:

[image]

Add a "Trigger/build on other projects" build step:

[image]

Trigger your job with the child job to launch:

[image]

It works:

[image]

I did a test with a list of two jobs and it works :)

Comment: How to pass if projects to build are many separated by commas?